# ALTERing SQL server function

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I am trying to alter a previously written SQL server 2008 function, but I keep getting a bunch of error codes. However the altered query should be ok, since I can run it separately as a query.

Updated query:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[list_acc]
(
  @ba_id int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(


    DECLARE @v1 varchar(40)
    @v1 varchar(40)
    SET @v1 = YEAR(GETDATE())
    SET @v1 += '/


    SELECT  BankingAccountStatementIdDW id ,
            StatementNumber nro ,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(10),StatementStartDate,104) startd,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(10),StatementEndDate,104) endd,
            StatementInitialBalance startm,
            StatementFinalBalance endm,
            StatementAvailableBalance inuse,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(10),DateCreated,104) made
    FROM Test.dbo.BankingAccountStatement bas
    WHERE bas.BankingAccountIdDW = @ba_id AND bas.StatementNumber <> @v1
)
```

Comment: No, changed the additional WHERE clause to the script that calls the stored procedure. I´m just gonna close this question as answered...

Comment: Thanks for you help everyone. I tried all the answers here, but it keeps giving me error related to @v1 and )

Comment: bas.StatementNumber = string/VARCHAR (runs ok on cmd)

Comment: it should not be an issue with the query syntax. If I run the SELECT query (as new query) and change @ba_id to a valid number (keeping the declaration and SET the same) I get the result I want

Comment: The only issue is/was altering the function on the DB. But changing it to the script calling the function is actually better solution, since I know where the impact shows (I do not know every place function might be called from)

Comment: remove the part where you declare the @v1 and move that code to the where clause, like I show in the second section...

Comment: is that the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the DECLARE part into the function body....

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[list_acc]
(
    @ba_id int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    DECLARE @v1 varchar(40)
    SET @v1 = CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/'
    .....
```

Or, since you're only using the variable in there where clause, you could get rid of the declare part and just add the code in the where...

```
FROM Test.dbo.BankingAccountStatement bas
WHERE bas.BankingAccountIdDW = @ba_id 
AND bas.StatementNumber <> CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/'
```

The query should look like this...

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[list_acc] ( @ba_id INT )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    ( SELECT    BankingAccountStatementIdDW id
               ,StatementNumber nro
               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), StatementStartDate, 104) startd
               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), StatementEndDate, 104) endd
               ,StatementInitialBalance startm
               ,StatementFinalBalance endm
               ,StatementAvailableBalance inuse
               ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DateCreated, 104) made
      FROM      Test.dbo.BankingAccountStatement bas
      WHERE     bas.BankingAccountIdDW = @ba_id
                AND bas.StatementNumber <> CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10))
                + '/'
    )
```

Comment: Still Incorrect syntax near '@v1' and Must declare the scalar variable "@ba_id".

Comment: You had `@v1` declared and set as a param

Comment: Missed comma in param list ba_id int,    v1 varchar(40)

Answer (score 0):

You have to rectify the error and execute it.

1. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure list_acc, Line 9
   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.

This error is because you have given a declare keyword in the function arguments.

change the code to..

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[list_acc]
(
    @ba_id int

)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
DECLARE @v1 varchar(40)
    SET @v1 = YEAR(GETDATE())
    SET @v1 += '/'

SELECT  BankingAccountStatementIdDW id ,
            StatementNumber nro ,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(10),StatementStartDate,104) startd,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(10),StatementEndDate,104) made,
            StatementInitialBalance startm,
            StatementFinalBalance endm,
            StatementAvailableBalance inuse,
            CONVERT(nvarchar(10),DateCreated,104) muodostettu
    FROM Test.dbo.BankingAccountStatement bas
    WHERE bas.BankingAccountIdDW = @ba_id AND bas.StatementNumber <> @v1
)

This should clear the errors.

Comment: Thanks, but still 2 errors remain: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure list_acc, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure list_acc, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near ')

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You cannot declare variables inside function parameters list

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[List_acc] (@ba_id INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(40)

      SET @v1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Year(Getdate()))
      SET @v1 += '/'

      RETURN
        (SELECT BankingAccountStatementIdDW                    id,
                StatementNumber                                nro,
                CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), StatementStartDate, 104) startd,
                CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), StatementEndDate, 104)   endd,
                StatementInitialBalance                        startm,
                StatementFinalBalance                          endm,
                StatementAvailableBalance                      inuse,
                CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DateCreated, 104)        made
         FROM   Test.dbo.BankingAccountStatement bas
         WHERE  bas.BankingAccountIdDW = @ba_id
                AND bas.StatementNumber <> @v1)
  END
```

Comment: Declaring the same variable twice?

Comment: @christiandev - Removed